# "Invalid literal operator name" error after including chrono library in a VS2017 MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-chrono

Everything works fine before including the chrono library in a VS project, but after I include the chrono library, multiple errors raised:

[image]

These errors are located at Line 892 in the 'chrono' file:

[image]

Under the variable `ns`, the error information is this:

Invalid literal operator name.

The compile environment is in the "Release" mode and "x64".

When I delete the `#include <chrono>`, everything works fine again.

What is reason for this problem? I need to use this library in the project.

Answer (score 2):

I wondered why the program only complains about the `ns` variable in the Chrono library. So I double-checked the program and found a huge mistake in a file: I defined `ns` as a macro. After changing the name of this macro, everything works fine.